# create a shared array with a tuple{Int,Char,String} as element type in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

Is there a way to create a Shared Array with data type of Tuple{Int,Char,String}?
I get an error saying the data type must be of bits type so I'm suspecting this is not possible and I can't find anything on the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/parallel/#shared-arrays) for `SharedArray` states

```
Construct a SharedArray of a bitstype T and size dims across the processes specified by pids - all
of which have to be on the same host.
```

so indeed, `T` must be a "bits" type. The actual restriction is that the type must be `isbits`, i.e. a "plain data" type. So for example, `Tuple{Int,Char}` is fine. But `String` is not plain data and so neither is `Tuple{Int,Char,String}`.

```
julia> isbits(Tuple{Int,Char,String})
false
```